# Start a remote scheduled task without administrator group

Tags: windows, permissions

we are currently evaluating the possibility to start an already created scheduled task remotely. I already know that we can use the command: schtasks /run /s computer /tn taskname and it work fine. The only thing is that it require to be a member on the administrator group. I know that you can do the same thing with powershell but the access right is the same.

So I would like to know if it is possible to give an access right to a user to be able to start the task without giving him admin? We want to use this solution to help manage centrally a lot of server and we don’t want our service account to be admin of every server. We want to enforce least privilege.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't functionality in the Task Scheduler in Windows Server 2008 (or newer versions, based on what I'm seeing) to delegate permission to start tasks to non-Administrator users.

Having said that, you could do something *creative* with the task's triggers as one possible option. I could imagine giving a non-Administrator user rights to write to the Application Event Log, then triggering the task based on a particular event. (I feel a little dirty even suggesting this, but it should work.)

There are third-party solutions that add the delegation functionality you're looking for, too.